# Xamarin Custom ViewCell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

while making custom nested views i faced a problem.
i'm trying to use my custom view(ViewCell) from various pages.
and this is how i used it.

it wont raise any error if i use View for Xaml and codebehind, 
but it wont display anything.

if i try ViewCell for xaml and its codebehind, i get some error.
and this is how i used it.

in mainPage xaml

```
 <local:UploaderCell Uploader="{Binding post.uploader}"/>
```

this is the line causing the error, and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EodiRoad;assembly=EodiRoad"
    xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="EodiRoad.SocialPage"
    Title="Story">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Icon="plus.png" Order="Primary" Priority="0" Activated="OnCreatePostClicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout>

        <ListView 
            x:Name="socialPostsListView" 
            HasUnevenRows="true" 
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" 
            Refreshing="Handle_Refreshing" 
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            ItemSelected="OnSocialPostSelected"
            >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5">
                            <local:UploaderCell Uploader="{Binding post.uploader}"/>


                            <Image
                                x:Name="postImage"
                                Source="{Binding post.image}"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                MinimumHeightRequest="200"
                            />


                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding post.isLiked}"/>
                                <Button Text="comment"/>
                                <Button Text="share"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding post.content}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding post.uploadedTime}" TextColor="Gray"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

this is my full mainPage xaml code.

---

in UploderCell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell
    xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="EodiRoad.UploaderCell">


    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
        <Button Clicked="Handle_Clicked" Image="{Binding Uploader.userProfile.userThumbnail}" BorderRadius="5" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>

        <ic:CircleImage 
            x:Name="userProfileImage"
            HeightRequest="50"
            WidthRequest="50"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Source="{Binding Uploader.userProfile.userThumbnail}"
        />

        <Label Text="{Binding Uploader.username}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

and the codeBehind

```
public partial class UploaderCell : ViewCell
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UploaderProperty = 
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "Uploader", 
                returnType: typeof(UserModel), 
                declaringType: typeof(UploaderCell)
            ); 

        public UserModel Uploader
        {
            get
            { return GetValue(UploaderProperty) as UserModel; }
            set 
            { SetValue(UploaderProperty, value); }
        }


        public UploaderCell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
  }
```

and i get this error from mainPage

```
object of type Project.UploaderCell cannot be converted to type 'xamarin.forms.view'
```

what am i doing wrong here?
how could i possibly fi this..

Comment: A cell can only be used within a ListView or a TableView.  It sounds like you are trying to use it directly in a page.  If that's what you need, use a ContentView instead.

Comment: actually i'm using it under viewcell which is at inside of list view... in this case, what should i use??

Comment: You need to show more context from your main page xaml.

Comment: Yes, you are trying to combine your custom cell with other elements inside of another ViewCell.  That's no t how a cell works.  Change your UploaderCell to inherit from ContentView instead.

Comment: well... then binding won't work properly. any additional proccess i should be doing?

Comment: could you lead me to a lecture or example projects or whatever about data binding in custom view, custom property? if you know one..

Comment: I know this is very late, but I'm looking into this myself at the moment and stumbled across the question. If you solved this, how? If not, is it as simple as changing your `<DataTemplate><ViewCell>…` to `<DataTemplate><local:UploaderCell>…` It looks to me as though you are tyring to place a custom `ViewCell` inside a `ViewCell`.